# Inappropriate ad in sidebar

Tags: discussion

Just now (but I have seen it earlier, and even clicked on it. It must be false) this ad appeared

[image]

What to do?

Comment: What was it, when you clicked on it?  Are you sure it isn't from SE?

Comment: It was one question that could be relevant, and then it started to ask about unrelated websites ... I doubt that SE would start a questionaire about CV without some information on meta!

Comment: " I doubt that SE would start a questionaire about CV without some information on meta!" - Haha.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out! This is an ad that we are running which should redirect you to a survey on Survey Monkey. We really appreciate hearing from you about the brands you're interested in so that we can serve ads that are most valuable to you.

**Update January 2021**

As a heads-up: We will be running a similar type of ad for a month or so.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  In light of Stephan Kolassa's [comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/inappropriate-ad-in-sidebar#comment19816_5893), it might be helpful in the future to let us know it's coming here in [meta.stats.SE].

Comment: No advertisements at all is my preference. (You did ask.)

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica - Thanks for the feedback :),  I'll try to let y'all know when I can, and I'm always happy to answer questions about ads as things come up here.